# Set Sheet Data before creating google Spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to create a spreadsheet. I am creating a spreadsheet with 3 sheets in it. Now I need to insert a row on each sheet before attaching them to the spreadsheet. Is there a way to populate the sheets with some data? All I want is to create the sheet in one request with all the data I need. Please see the below code for a better understanding:

```
<?php
class GoogleSheetFunctions {

public function create_new() {
    $client = $this->get_client();

    if ( is_null( $client ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $service = new Sheets( $client );
    $spreadsheet = $this->set_spreadsheet_title();
    $spreadsheet = $this->set_spreadsheet_with_sheets( $spreadsheet );

    // making the request to create a new spreadsheet in google
    try {
        $response = $service->spreadsheets->create( $spreadsheet );
        $spreadsheet_id = $response->spreadsheetId;
    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! $permission ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

protected function set_spreadsheet_with_sheets( Spreadsheet $spreadsheet ) {
    $sheet_names = [
        'sheet-no-1',
        'sheet-no-2',
        'sheet-no-3',
    ];

    $sheets = [];

    // creating sheets as per sheet names
    foreach ( $sheet_names as $sheet ) {
        $sheet_properties = new SheetProperties();
        $sheet_properties->setTitle( $sheet );
        $temp_sheet = new Sheet();
        $temp_sheet->setProperties( $sheet_properties );

        // generate a first row with custom data for each sheet

        $sheets[] = $temp_sheet;
    }

    // set the created sheets to the main spreadsheet
    $spreadsheet->setSheets( $sheets );

    return $spreadsheet;
}

protected function set_spreadsheet_title() {
    $month            = current_datetime()->format( 'F-Y' );
    $spreadsheet_name = $month;
    $spreadsheet_props = new SpreadsheetProperties();
    $spreadsheet_props->setTitle( $spreadsheet_name );
    $spreadsheet       = new Spreadsheet();
    $spreadsheet->setProperties( $spreadsheet_props );

    return $spreadsheet;
}

protected function get_client( $scopes = [] ) {
    $credential    = 'location/of/credential.json';

    $scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    ];

    return new Client( [
        'credentials' => $credential,
        'scopes'      => $scopes,
    ] );
}
}
```

Feel free to notify me of any queries. Sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: About your question of `Is there a way to populate the sheets with some data?`, I think that it's yes. But, if you want to request to modify your script, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine the expected result of your question. By this, I cannot propose a modified script. I apologize for this. So, if you want the modified script, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Could you clarify this part: `"Now I need to insert a row on each sheet before attaching them to the spreadsheet"`? Does that mean that you want to have the sheet created before even creating the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes @GabrielCarballo, that is the goal. I need the sheets with some data, then attach the sheets in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, that is totally ok. My English is not so good. My goal here:
I need the sheets with some data, then attach the sheets to the spreadsheet. By the way, I am using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), not the script. Feel free to notify me of any queries.